# CSS: Why are images shifted slightly down in Chrome?

Tags: css, html

I've got some images in a DIV tag and in Firefox, things are lined up nicely but when viewed in Chrome they are not.  I can't figure out why they get slightly pushed down in Chrome.

Site located at: http://www.realstockphotos.com

Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRhg0.jpg

Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP4rB.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give both inputs the same vertical alignment, e.g.:

```css
#searchFormTest input{vertical-align:middle;}
```

Comment: yep.. that did it.  Super big thanks. I've been fighting with that for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I put a `float: left` on the #searchPhrase input box and it appeared to help a bit, but I'm not sure if there's an even better fix for it.

Comment: I agree. It's because of vertical aligment, but the boxes should be in box model instead of inline model. So floating it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your input type has no value `<input type="submit" value="">`. 
When you put an empty space as the value it should work:`<input type="submit" value=" ">`